# Mobile web apps - Is this the right approach?

Tags: iphone, android, web-applications

I need to build a cross platform mobile app (iphone, android, etc). The app is for a company like a cellular operator (Tmobile, ATT). The app needs to do the following:

1. Show previous bills (cached so that it does not have to download everytime)
2. Need an internet connection to download newer bills, view recent data, etc.

Can I build a mobile web app to handle this? I understand that there is offline storage and iPhone has good support for web apps (full screen, good icons, offline, etc). Will a web app be the best approach to take as the app requires to be online? The app will not be used by lots of people, just customers of the website who don't want to use an existing website. We are all web developers and a mobile web app looks like the best way to approach this.

Comment: This is probably better suited to programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: `Show previous bills (cached so that it does not have to download everytime)` This looks like a pretty big security issue. You shouldn't store sensitive information on the phone.

Comment: @Falmarri, I just gave an example. There is nothing too sensitive in the data I am trying to store..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A webapp can target a wide range of devices, it has the advantage of being accessible without downloading or installation. Moreover, if later you need to bring your WebApp on other devices (not just iPhone or Android, but also BlackBerry, Bada ...) it is not necessary to reimplement everything.

For heavy features, data-intensive and graphically rich, or requiring API hardware (access to contacts, augmented reality ...), it is advisable to make native apps.

Otherwise, to ensure compatibility and visibility, and in order to reduce development time, WebApp approach may be preferred: there are now HTML5 API as local database or geolocation, and implementations of CSS3 that allow interesting rendering in a short time.

Look for example, the JavaScript toolkit **[Wink](http://www.winktoolkit.org)** that focuses on WebApps development: it allows to have simple and innovative components without having to learn a complex library.

Finally, Web views can be a way to build app using a WebApp, this allows App Store visibility, device API access ... which makes a evolution possible while keeping the existing code.

Answer (score 0):

> Will a web app be the best approach

That depends on your definition of best. It will probably be the fastest. However, mobile "apps" that are nothing but web browsers are normally terrible. You will probably be much better off in the long run writing 2 different apps using the native SDKs of the different platforms.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your requirements.

Web app (or more a web page) is faster to design and implement, however you will not be able to notify user, that some new bill is ready or stuff like that (for example some widget that checks if new bill arrived). You will also struggle with mobile browsers (especially JavaScript). However if you decide to create mobile application for each platform, you would be able to implement more features, but it will be much more time consuming. In this case I would suggest WebService and building clients based on platform-specific libraries. To sum it up, if you want to get it fast - Web page, if you want to have many features - mobile app + WebService.

Comment: `much more time consuming`. How much more time consuming depends considerably on how much of each platform the author already knows.

Comment: Yes and no, remember that you have to write the same mobile application several times: IPhone(Objective C), Android(Java), BlackBerry(J2ME-like) and others. These technologies has some parts in common (especially BB and Android), however there is a lot of platform specific code. And the last thing - Web Service (or other technology delivering data to mobile application) - solving communication issues is really time consuming (I used SOAP JAX-WS, but almost every library - either on Android or IPhone had bugs) So it seems much more time consuming to me.